# How to return JSON from Rails with camelcased key names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, camelcasing

I'm building a JS app with a Rails backend and in order not to confuse snake and camel cases, I want to normalize it all by returning camelcase key names from the server. So `user.last_name` would return `user.lastName` when returned from the API.

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

**Edit: Added Controller Code**

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
  # authorize_resource
  respond_to :json, only: [:index]
  def sky
      @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

      if @user
          obj =  {
              sky: {
                  sectors: @user.sectors,
                  slots: @user.slots
              }
          }

          render json: obj
      else
          raise "Unable to get Sky"
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

The way I do it is using ActiveModelSerializer and the json_api adapter:

In your Gemfile, add:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

Create a new file `/config/initializers/ams.rb` containing:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
```

Your controller action should look like this:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def sky
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

    if @user
      render json: @user, serializer: UserSkySerializer
    else
      raise "Unable to get Sky"
    end
  end
end
```

Now you need to create a serializer. First, create a new directory `app/serializers/`.

Next, create a new serializer `app/serializers/user_sky_serializer.rb`, containing:

```
class UserSkySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :sectors, :slots
end
```

The result will be similar to what you describe in your `obj` hash, but all attribute keys will be rendered in camelCase using the [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org) standard.

Comment: Thanks moveson, I did that and I'm getting an unserialized version of the json with `[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash` in my console. Any ideas here?

Comment: Could it be because if my inheritance? `class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base` (I combined the inheritance for brevity for this post)

Comment: FWIW, this is a Rails app, not a rails-api app

Comment: How are you setting `@resource` in your controller? Please edit your question to show the controller code.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this since ActiveModelSerializers seems like the best, least hacky way to achieve the lowercased camelcase that I'm going for in my API response. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackShapiro If you feel this answer was the most helpful, please choose it as the correct answer when you have a moment.

Comment: Can this be changed on-the-fly? All of our JSON is snake_case but a new vendor seems to prefer ClassCase. I only want to use ClassCase in serializers in their namespace. Is that possible?

Comment: @Dan I don't believe this can be changed without a server restart.

Comment: @moveson well that's a bummer. I'm not terribly surprised to hear that is the case. My plan now is to push back on the vendor asking for this. It's not often I am the customer and in a position to be bossy.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is the use the [olive_branch](https://github.com/vigetlabs/olive_branch) gem. As described in [this post](https://www.viget.com/articles/introducing-olivebranch/), all you need to do is:

1. Add this gem
2. add `config.middleware.use OliveBranch::Middleware` in `application.rb`.

Then, add this header to requests from your client-side app:

```
'X-Key-Inflection': 'camel'
```

If you are using libs like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), you can add this header to a constant along with other headers:

```
const HEADERS = {
  ...
  'X-Key-Inflection': 'camel'
}

const request = axios.post(url, param, HEADERS)
```

This way you don't need to `deep_transform` keys manually on the server side. Even deeply-nested json keys will be camelized. Example response from such request:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Bar",
    "createdAt": ...,
    "updatedAt": ...,
    ...
    "cabinAssignments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "cabinKeeperId": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "houseId": 1,
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your Rails version, so for others who look for this, I'll mention that in Rails 5 the answer is to use `#camelize` from `ActiveSupport::Inflector`. In my case, I had to call it in a chain on an `ActiveRecord` model (`t` below):

```
  def index
    trucks = AvailableTruck.all.map do |t|
      t.as_json(only: AvailableTruck.exposed)
       .deep_transform_keys(&:camelize).deep_transform_values(&:upcase)
    end
    render json: trucks
  end
```

`#deep_transform_keys` may or may not be necessary depending on your application.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5

Comment: What is `t` in your example? Can you give a little more context in your code please?

Comment: Then perhaps it will work better to use this approach?

Comment: Edited answer to provide additional context.

Comment: Thanks. Is there additional inheritance or conformation that my controller needs to do to work with `ActiveSupport::Inflector`?

Comment: I have `require active_support` and `require active_support/core_ext/hash/keys`, but I believe only the former is sufficient for just `camelize`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with ruby's `method_missing` method.

Create a file something like `concerns/method_missing_extension.rb` and put following code in it.

```
module MethodMissingExtension
  def method_missing(method_name, args = {})
    if self.class.column_names.include? method_name.to_s.underscore
      send method_name.to_s.underscore.to_sym
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Include this module in each model like `include MethodMissingExtension`.

Now whenever you do `user.firstName` then `user.first_name` will returned.

Comment: I hate downvote's without reason. Downvoters any reason to downvote?

Comment: Sure, I down voted because a similar answer already exists and I wrote a comment with the reason as to why. I only down voted as a signal for future people that come across this post as to where the correct answer may lay. Hope that clears it up

Comment: That answer is very different. Their implementation of `method_missing` is a bit different and need to create that for every attribute for each model. But, here it's only one time written module which can be included in all required `models` and you get the desired result. Hope it clarify your confusion.

Comment: And yes, if you can achieve something using your own little code then why to use some library or gem.

Comment: What I was going for, respectfully, is that I'm not interested in `method_missing`, because I'd have to implement it for every field on every model which is onerous and inefficient. My goal is to use `active_model_serializers`

Comment: Okay, it's your choice to use any option you want, our aim is try to provide an answer. And yes, you don't need to explicit implement `method_missing` for each attribute for each model. BTW, I'm not sure it won't help future readers. :)